# Lock wait timeout exceeded JPA inserting

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I know it seems duplicated, but I have been looking for a solutions in while.

I'm trying to insert two entities in the DB(Mysql) and I'm getting :
**ERROR: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction** 
I'm using JPA with Hibernate, and Spring for transaction control.

I already increased the timeout of Mysql, and tried to change the Entity Manager lock type to OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT.

I have the following entitys: 
Professional(Hiding other parts.):

```
@Entity(name = "Professional")
@Table(name = "professional")

    public class Professional implements Serializable {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Long id;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "professional")
        private Set<ProfessionalCurso> cursosProfissionais;

    }
```

Curso:

```
@Entity(name = "Curso")
@Table(name = "curso")
public class Curso implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -960848258531573118L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
}
```

ProfessionalCurso:

```
    @Entity(name = "ProfessionalCurso")
    @Table(name = "professional_curso")
    public class ProfessionalCurso implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -7896761710764415980L;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Long id;

@Column(name = "professional_id")
private Long professionalID;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "professional_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Professional professional;

@Column(name = "pais_id")
private Long paisID;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "pais_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Pais pais;

@Column(name = "instituicaoEnsinoID")
private Long instituicaoEnsinoID;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "instituicaoEnsinoID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private InstituicaoEnsino instituicaoDeEnsino;

@Column(name = "curso_id")
private Long cursoID;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "curso_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Curso curso;

// Categoria do curso introduzida pelo campo aberto
@Column(name = "categoria")
private String categoria;

@Column(name = "dataFormacao")
private Date dataFormacao;

}
```

While trying to insert using the following :

```
@Service
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public class ProfessionalService implements IProfessionalService {
@Override
    public void createProfessional(final Professional professional) {

        this.professionalDAO.save(professional);

        Set<ProfessionalCurso> cursosProfissionais = professional.getCursosProfissionais();
        for(ProfessionalCurso pcur : cursosProfissionais)
        {
            pcur.setProfessional(professional); 
            this.professionalCursoDAO.save(pcur);
        }
    }
}
```

My ProfessionalDAO and ProfessionalCursoDAO all of them extends from AbstractDAO:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public abstract class AbstractDAO<T> implements IAbstractDAO<T>, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8560745833920157266L;

    private EntityManager entityManager;

    private final Class<T> oClass;//object class

    public Class<T> getObjectClass() {
        return this.oClass;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public AbstractDAO()
    {
        this.oClass = (Class<T>)
                ( (ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass() ).
                getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }

    @Override   
    public T save(T object) {   
        getEntityManager().clear();
        //this.entityManager.lock(object, LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT);
        getEntityManager().persist(object);     
        return object;
    }
}
```

The stacktrace:

```
WARNING: #{criarProfessionalController.execute}: javax.persistence.LockTimeoutException: could not execute statement
javax.faces.FacesException: #{criarProfessionalController.execute}: javax.persistence.LockTimeoutException: could not execute statement
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:495)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:767)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1347)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: javax.persistence.LockTimeoutException: could not execute statement
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.LockTimeoutException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.wrapLockException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1812)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1715)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1683)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1187)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:344)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy31.persist(Unknown Source)
    at co.mz.mukhero.fme.dao.AbstractDAO.save(AbstractDAO.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy50.save(Unknown Source)
    at co.mz.mukhero.fme.service.ProfessionalService.createProfessional(ProfessionalService.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy53.createProfessional(Unknown Source)
    at co.mz.mukhero.fme.controller.CriarProfessionalController.execute(CriarProfessionalController.java:712)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:247)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:267)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.LockTimeoutException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect$1.convert(MySQLDialect.java:447)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:211)
    at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3032)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3558)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:492)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:197)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:216)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:324)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:288)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:811)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:784)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:789)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1181)
    ... 73 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:996)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3887)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3823)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2435)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2530)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1907)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2141)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2077)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2062)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208)
    ... 94 more
```

Comment: Stacktrace please

Comment: added to the question.

Comment: Do you get the exception at line `this.professionalDAO.save(professional);` or after that?

Comment: after.
Exactly when Hibernate try to insert into professionalCurso. Running the line this.professionalCursoDAO.save(pcur);

Comment: [`flush()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#flush--)`Professional` and [`refresh()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#refresh-java.lang.Object-) it after persisting it to the DB so that you can retrieve the auto-generated ID.

Comment: add the following to my abstractDAO : getEntityManager().refresh(object); but the problem persist.

Comment: just (another) guess: In your service method ... 1. put the for loop to the top, but 2. don't save the "cursos" ...only `setProfessional()` ! 3. (only) save the professional (at the end of method) . analysis: Timeout happens because `professionalCursoDAO.save(pcur)` ...also tries to save the professional, which exactly is locked by the same transaction. ..alternatively you can "play" with the cascade settings.

Comment: @Rabbit You've (1)`persisted`, (2)`flushed` and (3)`refreshed` your   `Professional`?

Comment: @janezKuhar I don't have the flushed .

Comment: guys! nothing work .! 
any help ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in your shared DAO ancestor in the line

```
getEntityManager().clear();
```

first, you should rarely, if ever, call clear, and it should not be on every save, as clear attempts to remove the entity cache.

second, in this particular case, you attempt to call clear on a changed entity, which means that it's going to wait and see if you commit the transaction to whether or not to update the DB, or throw away the change.  This is where the entity lock happens.

Comment: I removed the line, know just doing getEntityManager().persist(object);  

But still, not working.